# Javascript - Adding unique item to array in loop but array keeps repeating values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an empty array which i try to add unique  objects (checkedAccounts) in a for loop. I log the unique objects in a console so i can confirm they are all unique. funny thing is, after the loop my array repeats the same value of the last index.

So in a case of adding [1,2,3] to the empty array inside a for loop,
instead of getting [1,2,3] i get [3,3,3]

find below my 2 different approaches that didnt work

```
//Approach 1

let finalAccounts:any[] = [];
let item:any = this.productModel;

let i:number = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < checkedAccounts.length; i++){
    item.accountNo = checkedAccounts[i].accountNo;
    item.accountName = checkedAccounts[i].accountName;
    item.accountType = checkedAccounts[i].accountType;
    finalAccounts[i] = item;
    console.log('item in loop ' + i, item);
    console.log('Final acounts in loop ' + i, finalAccounts);
  }

  console.log('Final Accounts', finalAccounts);





  //Approach 2

  let finalAccounts:any[] = [];
  let item:any = this.productModel;

  for(let account of checkedAccounts){
    temp.accountNo = account.accountNo;
    temp.accountName = account.accountName;
    temp.accountType = account.accountType;
    finalAccounts.push(temp);
    console.log('temp'+checkedAccounts.indexOf(account),temp);
  }
```

Comment: `let finalAccounts:any[] = [];` what is this syntax?

Comment: @omri_saadon, that's a typescript

Comment: @SET, One day i'll find the time to learn it :) Thanks

Comment: @omri_saadon, you will never get back to vanilla js then )

Comment: You only have one object, `item`. Each time you change the properties, such as `accountNo`, it's also changing the ones you've already pushed into your array

Comment: simple initialise `let item:any = this.productModel;` inside for loop which solves your issue . you cant share instance

Comment: Interesting, can you suggest a workaround? @user184994

Comment: You should make sure you declare a new `item` in each iteration of the loop

Comment: I believe that was the first thing i did and it still didnt work. i moved it outside the loop thinking it was the issue. let me try again and give u feedback. @supercool

Comment: i still get the same error. the last item is repeated. this is confusing tbh. @user184994

Comment: @AbEbube I've posted an answer below, give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have a fresh copy of the `item` in each loop iteration. Using the syntax below, we can create a shallow copy. Try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < checkedAccounts.length; i++){
    let item:any = {...this.productModel};
    item.accountNo = checkedAccounts[i].accountNo;
    finalAccounts.push(item);
}
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: THIS WORKS! Thank you! @user184994

Comment: @AbEbube Glad to help. If you get a minute, feel free to accept the answer using the green tick

Answer (score 0):

you can't share instance inside foreach while you push to a array i.e make it independent.

**couple of observations**

1) If you want to use **any**(strictly avoid, use it only if you are not sure about type) then there is no point using `let item:any = {...this.productModel}` you can simply achive same using `let item:any = {}`

2) preferable way will be *typeScript* way using **interfaces**

**Code:**

```
finalAccounts: IntTest[] = [];

export interface productModel {
  accountNo: string;
  address?: string;
}

for (i = 0; i < checkedAccounts.length; i++) {
  let item: IntTest = {
    accountNo: checkedAccounts[i].accountNo
  };
  finalAccounts.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Better to shallow copy the productmodel

Comment: This isn't going to be any better, as it's still setting `item` to the same object on each iteration

Comment: @AbEbube updated answer for info . hope it helps to understand better.